# Is there any way to get edit branch protection rules in a mirrored repo in local?

Tags: git, github, branch, github-api, git-branch

I'm trying to migrate a repo which has branch protection rules from Github Enterprise Server to Github Enterprise Cloud.

After cloning and pushing the mirror repo using `git clone --mirror` and `git push --mirror` commands.

After this clone and push, I'm trying to rename branches in my local (from `master` to `main`).

I already have branch protection rules pushed as part of `push --mirror`. and If I rename the branch locally from `master` to `main`, it's throwing error because the `master` branch itself gets deleted entirely.

I'm looking if there is a way to edit the the protection rules locally in the mirror repo even before pushing it to Github Cloud.

I did look at the contents of the mirror repo. But can't seem to find where the branch protection rules exists in mirror repo if any.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'm not 100% proficient in github's setting, but I would guess you have the branch protection rules on that "mirror" repo because they were somehow copied on the github side of things, AFAIK these rules do not appear in any git object which you would get from a `git clone` or a `git clone --mirror`.

Comment: Yeah. I don't see them. But them must be somewhere definitely. Otherwise how would the new repo know about branch protection rules.

Comment: How did you create this mirror repo on github ? did you click on some form of "clone repository" or "copy repository" in the github GUI ?

Comment: I did create an empty repo on GHEC, mirror cloned repo from GHES using `--mirror` and pushed the same using `--mirror`.

Comment: oh, isn't the protection on master a default rule when you create an empty repository ?

Comment: No. What I'm doing is basically pushing the mirror repo as it is. *and then after* renaming branches in local and pushing them again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251210/discussion-between-legec-and-underoos).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest :

- go to the github GUI of your mirror repo, and remove the protection rule on `master`,
- push your renamed branch (either through a full `git push --mirror`, or `git push origin <local main>:main; git push origin --delete master`)
- on the github GUI set a protection rule on `main`

---

[edit]

with additional information in your comment, you indicate that you need to do this several times for a whole list of repositories, and that you are using the `gh` cli tool.

- you can use github [API for protected branches](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection?apiVersion=2022-11-28) to script a way to remove the rule on `master` and add it on `main`
- you may use [`gh api` to do so](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api)

Reading the doc for the API, I don't see a way to update the `rule` field -- the field you can set in Github's GUI.

You could write a script that:

- gets the current protection settings for `master`
- creates a new rule with similar settings for `main`
- deletes the rule for `master`

Comment: I'm actually looking to migrate multiple repos which have branch protection rules. So, manually removing and adding again would be cumbersome.

Comment: in that case : check the API ([link to docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/branches/branch-protection?apiVersion=2022-11-28))

Comment: Is there any way to just rename the pattern in branch protection?